# Is the primitve element of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots]/\mathbb{Q}$ always $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \cdots$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have dealt with a number of algebraic field extensions $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots]/\mathbb{Q}$ and the primitive element was always $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \cdots$. Is this generally true (provided that there exists a primitive element in the first place) or are there counter examples?

Comment: Certainly not in general, I mean $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2, -\sqrt 2)$ is a counterexample. There are probably less trivial ones too.

Comment: @NoahOlander Slightly less trivial: $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2]$

Comment: @Eoin My counterexample fulfills your condition

Comment: In general, you can construct counterexamples based on the constructive proof of the primitive element theorem. See for example, http://planetmath.org/ProofOfPrimitiveElementTheorem and note that you just need to gimmick your generators so that the sum is one of the exceptions.

Comment: It is true that, for finitely many algebraic $\alpha_i$'s, there are primitive elements among their *linear combinations*.

Comment: As Hagen's answer mentions, *there is no such thing as "the" primitive element*; there will be many equally-good choices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it is easy to construct explicit counterexamples, one might ask why it happens so often in naturally occuring situations that the sum is primitive. The reason is that *almost all* linear combinations of the $\alpha_k$ are primitive; recall from the proof that one uses that the inifinitely many fields $\mathbb Q[\alpha_1+c\alpha_2]$ are really just finitely many, and ultimately *almost all* choices of $c$ lead to a primitive element. Hence a case where $c=1$ does not work can be assumed to be "bad luck" or artificially constructed to have this property (such as $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2]$)

Comment: In this case $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}] = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}]$. How about when we have $\mathbb{Q}[S]$ with $S$ a minimal set?